# Sql Join with Customizable View

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have 2 table user_log and user_plan.
I write a query using join :

```
SELECT distinct user_log.user_id,user_plan.month_plan_id 
    FROM user_plan 
    LEFT JOIN user_log ON user_plan.user_id = user_log.user_id 
    WHERE user_log.user_id != ''
```

Return Value:

```
user_id month_plan_id
1   4
1   2
1   1
43  3
43  2
46  3
74  1
74  3
```

But i want to customize and its looks like:

```
user_id month_plan_id
1   4,2,1   
43  3,2 
46  3
74  1,3
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use it with GROUP_CONCAT

try this:

```
  SELECT user_id, group_concat(month_plan_id) as month_plan_id 
  FROM your_table
  GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: Not working :(
   
 user_id month_plan_id 
 1 [BLOB - 23 B] 
 31 [BLOB - 1 B] 
 32 [BLOB - 1 B]

I think casting Error.

Comment: @Rahul [BLOB - 23 B ?? where is this in your question ?

Comment: show your real query please . i gave answer to what you gave in your question

Comment: SELECT user_id, group_concat(month_plan_id) as month_plan_id 
  FROM user_plan GROUP BY user_id

===========================================

SELECT user_id, group_concat(month_plan_id separator ',') as month_plan_id FROM user_plan GROUP BY user_id

Comment: but its wrong what are you doing. please show it in your question and tell what you want.

Comment: you dont have to make separator , its already separated by comma.

Comment: Its working Now:

SELECT user_id, group_concat(CONVERT(month_plan_id,CHAR(8))) as month_plan_id FROM user_plan GROUP BY user_id